# Can I upgrade committed use discount from 1 year to 3 year?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

If I purchase a 1 year committed use discount, can I upgrade it to 3 years and get more discount percentage?
No purchased resource modified.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I cannot find close menu or button to close this question. How to close it??

Comment: I vote to keep the question, billing questions about expensive server resources are valid questions and i don't know where else one would put them except here.

Answer (score 0):

By defaultn you can't as explained in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts#changing_a_commitment). However, try to contact the support or your Google Cloud Sale or Customer Engineer about that.

Answer (score 0):

I was denied the ability to change from 3 year to 1 year and asked to just paying the difference with google support. I assume the same could be true in your case.